# Move files in bulk and create links in their place in the directory in linux

Tags: linux, find, mv, ln

I am trying to move hundreds of files from one directory to another but create a softlink in the old directory while doing that. Is there a single line command that can do that?

`/dir1
file1.txt
file2.txt
.
.
.
file100.txt`

move to dir2 and create soft link to them in dir1.

I am currently doing that seperately but was hoping to find a single line command if possible.

`cd dir1
mv *.txt /dir2
ln -s /dir2/*.txt .`

I tried using `find` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single line command.  It's quite trivial to do with shell scripting.  For example, in tcsh:

```
% cd dir1
% foreach FILETOMOVE ( file*.txt )
     echo mv -iv $FILETOMOVE /dir2
     echo ln -s /dir2/$FILETOMOVE .
     end
```

(Remove the *echo*'s once you're sure you've got it right.)

Bash is similar, with slightly different syntax.

This is slightly more complicated if the filenames or paths include spaces, but still quite simple.  (:q in tcsh, using "", etc.)